# create alias class from generic type typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

how can convert generic type that pass class call as  alias class

```
class Test<A>{

     constructor(a){
  
      callFunction(a)

    }
  

}


//1 - when call this class That will be like this

import C from '../C'

let t=new Test<C>(C)

//2- l want to call this class like this without pass C again 

let t=new Test<C>()
```

so l mean there are way pass C to "callFunction" without pass as constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
//2- l want to call this class like this without pass C again 

let t=new Test<C>()
```

Types only exists at compile time, and when the program is running the types are no longer there. So `new Test<C>()` just compiles to `new Test()` and the `C` is totally gone. This means there is no value to pass to `callFunction`.

But what you can do is go the other direction and infer the type of the generic from a parameter.

For example:

```
class Test<A>{
    constructor(public a: A) {
        callFunction(a)
    }
}

type C = { something: string }

const c: C = { something: 'foo' }

let t = new Test(c) // t is typed as Test<C>

t.a.something // fine
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQMXNeYAUKATgOYBci4A1mHAO5gCUiA3gL4BQXEaKAzn0QAVAKZ8oAHgCCAPhYdEi5AnFEQ0OEXwAHEACM0MCIhQUpzeQEglydFhywEhRgqWdOXDlACe2kYgBhRABeVkQ+OABbESgACxgwcnCoIgSSRA8IFShkCiDQlnComPjEigByYDg4coyuNBjEHNCwETphMSh8CGYAel6mxBhBHz8AExNBUXEJAJkuKAA6FEWI6Li0xH7EYASRDiA)